# Difference in parameter estimates between pandas autocorr() and statsmodels ARIMA

Tags: python, pandas, arima

I have a fairly basic question. I'm trying to fit a very basic AR1 model
y(t) = a + b* y(t-1) + epsilon

sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
np.random.seed(42)
lData = np.random.normal(size=100)
lData = pd.Series(lData)
lData.autocorr()
```

The above code gives the autocorrelation coefficient as -0.0215481

```
lAR1 = ARIMA(lData, order = (1,0,0))
lAR1_fit = lAR1.fit()
lAR1.params
```

The above code gives the ar.L1 estimate as -0.021392

Shouldn't the two results be the same ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are missing something about ar.L1 value.`lAR1_fit.pvalues` is giving me `ar.L1`= `8.355478e-01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two points here.

First, the estimate of the coefficient in the AR(1) model is not related to (auto)correlation but TO a regression coefficient of `lData[1:]` on `lData[:-1]` which can be calculated by hand

```
np.corrcoef(lData[1:],lData[:-1])*np.std(lData[1:])/np.std(lData[:-1])
```

to be equal to **-0.0215023**:

```
array([[ 0.99787211, -0.0215023 ],
       [-0.0215023 ,  0.99787211]])
```

Second, ARIMA implements a number of fit methods that produce slightly different results, see [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.fit)
The default, is far as I can tell, is 'innovations_mle', as

```
lAR1_fit = lAR1.fit(method = 'innovations_mle')
```

produces the same results as without `method = ...` spec.

the closest to the standard regression on lagged values is, as far as I can tell, the `'yule_walker'` method:

```
lAR1_fit = lAR1.fit(method = 'yule_walker')
```

This produces **-0.021508** which is pretty close to what we got by hand in the regression calc -- the difference can be attributed to rounding errors in numerical calcs

```
const    -0.103945
ar.L1    -0.021508
sigma2    0.816144
dtype: float64
```